# Is there a way to set a date and time (timezone) in Azure DevOps CI/CD build pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration

I have automated test running in my CI/CD build pipeline, but the time in DevOps is UTC and my assertions tests check the local time.
Is there a way to set a time zone in my build pipeline?

Comment: No. You have a bigger problem: Your tests rely on an external dependency. You would have this exact same problem if you hired a remote developer in a different timezone. Fix your tests or fix your date handling code to be timezone agnostic.

Comment: I agree it's good to be timezone agnostic when possible, but not sure that tone is fair. Dependencies are not *always* evil. Integration tests, for example, might rely on external test environments -- I personally write integrations for a system that is both timezone-unaware and completely out of my control to fix. As such, I have a hard requirement that my code (and tests) always be run on a server whose timezone matches that of the system I'm integrating with.

Answer (score 10):

using Powershell, you can do:

```
Get-TimeZone
Set-TimeZone "India Standard Time"
Get-TimeZone
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes. For example this simple BASH script run using a Microsoft Hosted Agent:

```
echo "checking date"
date
echo "setting date to Asia/Kolkata"
sudo timedatectl set-timezone "Asia/Kolkata"
date
```

The results as seen in the log:

```
2019-07-05T20:26:48.5992486Z checking date
2019-07-05T20:26:48.5992954Z Fri Jul  5 20:26:48 UTC 2019
2019-07-05T20:26:48.5993264Z setting date to Asia/Kolkata
2019-07-05T20:26:48.9107025Z Sat Jul  6 01:56:48 IST 2019
```

As you can see, you can manipulate the local time on the agent. I do not agree with the other poster that this is necessarily a bad thing to do in the context of running tests.

You put some extra code in your tests to account for the local / target time or you could add 1 line into your build agent and achieve the same thing.

It just depends, the devil is in the details. Be careful with how you handle time.

Comment: This works if vmImage is ubuntu but not if it's `windows-latest`

Answer (score 2):

Asia/Kolkata and "sudo timedatectl set-timezone" is not working on mac OS vmimage.  Use below task for mac.

```
 - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: Set system Timezone to IST
    inputs:
      script: |
        sudo systemsetup -gettimezone
        sudo systemsetup -settimezone Asia/Calcutta
        sudo systemsetup -gettimezone
```

Also you can use this command to get the list of all valid timezones

```
sudo systemsetup -listtimezones
```

Answer (score 1):

If ubuntu agent is used, the following commands can be used.

- List timezones: `timedatectl list-timezones`
- Set timezone: `sudo timedatectl set-timezone '<your timezone>'`

Answer (score 0):

Additional to other replies for Windows Powershell and Linux Bash,
Mac OSX agent such xcode or Xamarin.iOS should use the script below to set timezone:

```
- task: Bash@3
    displayName: Set Mac OS X Timezone
    inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: sudo systemsetup -settimezone Asia/Shanghai
```