# Azure Pipelines: use local time for file modified timestamp instead of UTC

Tags: iis, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have multistage Azure Pipeline building a .NET Core 3.1 Web API on a hosted agent.

When the site is deployed to our on-premise IIS servers and I look at them in file explorer, the "date modified" timestamps of the built assemblies is behind by 13 hours, as if it is showing UTC instead of local time.  Other files on the same box show local time.  I'd like to have my deployed files show the local time too.

How do I do that?

Comment: About how to "show the local time", you should refer to the user manual of the software you use (Windows Explorer?). When the file is modified, Windows sets the time based on UTC, which is clearly documented by Microsoft, which you cannot change, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/file-times

Comment: Any other file I change on the IIS server receives local time; why should these ones be any different?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the method in the link provided by Nick.McDermaid.

Running bash script with a Microsoft Hosted Agent:

```
echo "checking date"
date
echo "setting date to Asia/Kolkata"
sudo timedatectl set-timezone "Asia/Kolkata"
date
```

The results:

```
2019-07-05T20:26:48.5992486Z checking date
2019-07-05T20:26:48.5992954Z Fri Jul  5 20:26:48 UTC 2019
2019-07-05T20:26:48.5993264Z setting date to Asia/Kolkata
2019-07-05T20:26:48.9107025Z Sat Jul  6 01:56:48 IST 2019
```

You can manipulate the local time on the agent.

Comment: I can't just log in and use the desktop - it's an azure pipeline hosted agent.

Comment: Does this make any difference? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/change-time-zone?view=azure-devops

Comment: This has some examples of running scripts in your pipeline to set the timezone on the hosted agent https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56901952/is-there-a-way-to-set-a-date-and-time-timezone-in-azure-devops-ci-cd-build-pip

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late for the party but here is how I fix this.

I am deploying an ancient Asp.net app that uses WebResource.axd and the wrong timestamp in the dll files causes some embedded resources to not be found (404 errors). When the web server time catches up with the dll last modified time,  everything works just fine.

Since I am building at an Azure hosted agent (not private), first I run a PowerShell script in the **build job** to set the build agent timezone:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Set agent timezone'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Set-TimeZone -Id "E. South America Standard Time" -PassThru
```

Now the build artifact produced by the build is a zip file which does have the dll files with the correct timestamp (in my case UTC -3). This can be verified by downloading the build artifact from DevOps. But, at the target web server the deployed dlls still have the incorrect UTC timestamp.

This is caused by the **IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup** task with the option **XmlVariableSubstitution** set to **true**. If you look at the build agent folder in your web server, you will see the problem.

The zip file at c:\azagent\A1_work\1\drop does have the correct UTC -3 timestamp as expected but, because of the variable substitution option, it will create another temporary zip file at c:\azagent\A1_work\s and this one have the files with UTC timestamp, these are the files that end up in your target folder.

To fix this, just disable the XmlVariableSubstitution option of the IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup task and add a FileTransform task, for instance:

```
- task: IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
  displayName: 'IIS Web App Deploy'
  inputs:
    WebSiteName: 'ParentSite'
    VirtualApplication: '/virtualpath'
    Package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)\drop\myproject.zip'
    RemoveAdditionalFilesFlag: true
    TakeAppOfflineFlag: true
    XmlVariableSubstitution: false

- task: FileTransform@1
  displayName: 'Replace variables'
  inputs:
    folderPath: 'c:\sites\mysite\wwwroot' 
    fileType: xml
    targetFiles: |
      *.config
```

Now, if you deploy the application you will find the files in the target folder does have the correct timestamps.