# Can the timezone of a hosted agent in azure devops be changed?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm moving ancient code from an existing test infrastructure to ADO. Some of this code relies on the fact that it's never been run outside of PST (questionable date math). Is there some way to configure or reset the timezone in a windows hosted agent in devops? I tried just executing tzutil, but it wasn't found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the following sample bash script using Microsoft hosted agent to configure the timezone.

```
echo "checking date"
date
echo "setting date to Asia/Kolkata"
sudo timedatectl set-timezone "Asia/Kolkata"
date
```

The results in the log:

```
2019-07-05T20:26:48.5992486Z checking date
2019-07-05T20:26:48.5992954Z Fri Jul  5 20:26:48 UTC 2019
2019-07-05T20:26:48.5993264Z setting date to Asia/Kolkata
2019-07-05T20:26:48.9107025Z Sat Jul  6 01:56:48 IST 2019
```

You can refer to this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56901952/is-there-a-way-to-set-a-date-and-time-timezone-in-azure-devops-ci-cd-build-pip) for details.