# Why is PublishTestResults@2 aborting with "value results in an un-representable DateTime" warning?

Tags: azure-devops, junit, azure-pipelines, devops, tosca

I have a test-list which is executed by TOSCA and produces a JUnit compatible test-result. I then use `PublishTestResults@2` to import the test-results into DevOps. However I get this error:

```
Failed to parse result files:  The added or subtracted value results in an un-representable DateTime.
```

[image: Error Message]

It's marked a warning but no test-results are imported. Considering that the test set runs for 2 hour this is quite disappointing.

Does anybody know why this error happen and what can be done about it?

Answer (score 1):

> Failed to parse result files:  The added or subtracted value results in an un-representable DateTime.

The cause of this issue is usually that the time field value in the test result file is too large.

For example:

```
<testcase name="Global Search" time="xxxxxxxxxxxx.xxx"
```

The counting unit of time is seconds. If its value is too large (exceeds the current time after conversion). It will show the error message.

For a workaround, you can manually modify the time value to a small number.

For example:

```
<testcase name="Global Search" time="1"
```

Then you can use the Publish Test Result task to publish the test result again.

On the other hand, you need to check whether there are settings that will cause huge test time values to be generated when executing tests with TOSCA.

Comment: Interesting. Yes it's a test set running for about 2 hours on three agents in parallel. I can see two problems: (1) DevOps runs on UTC which is about 2 hours from local time. (2) 3 * 2 hour are 6 hours which will be in the future of DevOps adds them up without noticing that the test where run in parallel.

Comment: @Martin  You can try to set the timezone before running the Publish the test result task and check if it can work. PowerShell commnad: **Set-TimeZone "xxxStandard Time"** Refer to this ticket:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56901952/is-there-a-way-to-set-a-date-and-time-timezone-in-azure-devops-ci-cd-build-pip